# FORMULA FIELD ERROR saying missing bracket

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, formula

I have a requirement which states that if `Account.Agreement_type__c` and `Opportunity.Agreement_type__c` are not blank and if both the values are the same then return 1 or else 0

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Agreement_type__c)) AND NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.Agreement_type__c)) 
AND (TEXT(Account.Agreement_type__c) == TEXT(Opportunity.Agreement_type__c)),1,0)
```

I m getting a error as missing `(` and don t know whether this codes works as per my requirement or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your field names and relationships are correct, cleaner way of writing a validation would be something like below :

```
IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Agreement_type__c)),
NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.Agreement_type__c)),
TEXT(Account.Agreement_type__c) == TEXT(Opportunity.Agreement_type__c)
),TRUE,FALSE)
```

PS : Or you could go with below approach and put "AND"  as "&&" in between statements -

```
    NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Agreement_type__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.Agreement_type__c)) && 
TEXT(Account.Agreement_type__c) == TEXT(Opportunity.Agreement_type__c)
```

Both solution will result in same thing.

Comment: You don't need the `IF` at all in this case.

Comment: Yep but didn't want to sway author much away from his answer, its just another way of saying same thing

Comment: Using `IF(condition, true, false)` instead of just `condition` can make formulas harder to understand, in addition to being inefficient.